# Why does this "read file" function I've created in C behave differently in Linux than it does in Windows?

Tags: c

I am using this function to read in a text file that contains strings which are read in and inserted into an AVL tree. Everything works perfectly fine in Windows, however once I try to run it in Linux it produces entirely different results (I get a bunch of redundant nodes whose keys are simply blank spaces). Would anyone be able to explain why this might be the case?

```
node *read_file(char *list_name)
{
    char array[255];
    char *token = NULL;
    node *found = NULL; 
    node *tree = NULL;
    FILE *file = fopen(list_name, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets(array, 255, file) != NULL) 
    {
        token = strtok(array, " \n"); 
        while (token != NULL)      
        {       
            found = find_key(token, tree);

            if (found == NULL)
            {
                tree = insert(token, tree);
            }
            else 
            {
                found->frequency++;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n"); 
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: `char array[255];` should be `char array[255 + 1];`

Comment: @xing: I don't think so; `fopen(...,"r")` is "text mode" and should handle this distinction correctly.

Comment: @xing: hmm - I always thought this would be handled neatly. You are probably right.

Comment: The most likely reason is the opposite one, a file that came from a Unix machine and contains only \n as a line break.  fgets() will return those on a Windows machine.  So the loop was never tested on a Unix machine and code that is not tested is broken by design :)

Comment: @xing: Your solution worked, thank you! I created the original text file in Windows and then ported it in a tar file to Linux so that explains everything.

Comment: @sturcotte06: why should I add '+ 1' ?

Comment: @wallZ Because of the null char.

Comment: @wallZ if your text file has more than 255 characters, UB awaits you.

Comment: nvm I'm wrong, as per `fgets` documentation: `n − This is the maximum number of characters to be read (including the final null-character). Usually, the length of the array passed as str is used.`

Comment: Since you show neither the `find_key()` nor the `insert()` functions, we can't tell what you're doing wrong in them.  However, most likely, you are not making copies of the data properly, and you keep reusing the same space provided to `fgets()` for the new keys, overwriting the old keys, and completely wrecking the BST you're attempting to build.

Comment: You talk about nodes, but _what is a node?_.  Please, don't explain the things at half.  Read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @xing, you might want to put your solution as an answer here.

Comment: @sturcotte06, I'm afraid not, you don't need to add one to the size of `array`.  He had better use `sizeof array` in the call to `fgets(3)` to avoid mistakes if he later changes the size of the array, but there's no need to consider the final `\0` character, as `fgets(3)` does that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues using `stdio` in windows respect unix (or linux) just use always `b` specifier to `fopen(3)` call.  Line terminators in unix consist on a single `\n` char, while in windows they are composed of a sequence of `\r\n` characters.  The solution adopted by the windows port consist in allowing you to specify `"rt"`, instead of `"r"` to the `fopen(3)` call, so the `\r` are filtered out before passing them to the calling code.  Probably your problem will be solved by just using `"rt"` instead of `"r"` (Posix spec allows this flag to be used in unix, but ignores it, so using it always is no harmful)   There's another `"b"` specifier, that allows you to consider the file a binary file (so the transformation of eliminating all the `\r` chars isn't done.  This is mainly mean for binary files.